# ¿porque el metodo onClick de un control boton no funciona?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

tengo un boton que al precionar muestra un modal y cargue los datos de una consulta pero al presionar no reacciona el metodo en el codigo de C# al hacer pruebas nunca entra al metodo.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnaddRequest" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MLrequest" Text="Agregar" OnClick="btnaddRequest_Click" />
```

en C#

```
protected void btnaddRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lblCprovidier.Text = "0";
        lblCproductos.Text = "0";
        lblCcot.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: El problema seguramente esta en el modal, ya que las peticiones hacen que se recargue el navegador y que nunca se muestre desde un control de servidor, te recomiendo que previamente cargues los datos en el modal y que muestres este modal desde javascript.

Comment: me podrias mostrar un ejemplo de como se hace? en web aun no se muy bien la logica  de eventos que pasa entre javascript y C#

Comment: Tu modal es de bootstrap verdad?

Comment: Agregale el siguiente atributo al buton y dime si te funciono:  `CausesValidation="False"`

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la idea, primero cargas los datos en los labels en el evento onload (o en el evento que mejor se acomode), y ya con los datos cargados en el DOM, procedes a lanzar el modal con javascript o en el mismo botón.

Control html evita recargar la página.

```
<button href="#" id="btnTriggerModalEFNT" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="MLrequest">Agregar</button>
```

Carga de datos con c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lblCprovidier.Text = "0";
            lblCproductos.Text = "0";
            lblCcot.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

No olvides revisar la consola del navegador para ver si tienes otros problemas como no haber cargado jquery o alguna falla de sintaxis en el javascript.

Comment: entonces el boton no puede abrir un modal y cargar datos a la vez? porque lo ocupare mas adelante cuando quiera editar un registro y al precionar aparesca con los datos de la fila que escogio

Comment: Creo entender lo que buscas, pero en efecto no podrás abrir un modal y ejecutar una petición de servidor, porque como te dije se recargara la página y el modal se cerrara, puedes hacer algo mejor. En el evento "ready" lanzas el modal, y con respecto a tu botón de editar debes hacer que al finalizar todo su proceso redireccione  a la misma página. Te escribiré otra respuesta para que sepas como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta es para responder a tu otro caso donde quieres mostrar los cambios en un modal, como dije antes se debe cargar los datos en el evento onload y se debe redireccionar a la misma página al finalizar tus procesos con el control de servidor.

```
javascript

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnTriggerModalEFNT').modal('show');
});
```

con c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblCprovidier.Text = "0";
        lblCproductos.Text = "0";
        lblCcot.Text = "0";
        ListarRegistros(); // generas un procedimiento para listar tus registros
    }
}

        protected void btnaddRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Realizas todo tu proceso
        Response.Redirect("~/TuPagina.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor no escribas dos respuestas, y mas si OP hizo otra pregunta diferente. deberia crear una pregunta diferente y vos poner la respuesta ahi, porque de esta forma no se sabe cual es la respuesta correcta, y esta respuesta es confusa, porque mas que todo contesta una pregunta que no se hizo

Comment: ya no carga el modal , primero si se mostró pero después se quito y se quedo la pantalla gris, lo raro que si vuelvo a correr la pagina se siguio la pantalla gris